# Splunk query not endswith

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I am just into learning of Splunk queries, I'm trying to grab a data from `myfile.csv` file based on the `regex` expression.

In particular, I'm looking forward, print only the rows where column `fqdn` not endswith `udc.net` and `htc.com`.

Below is my query which is working but i'm writing it twice.

```
| inputlookup myfile.csv 
| regex support_group="^mygroup-Linux$" 
| regex u_sec_dom="^Normal Secure$" 
| regex fqdn!=".*?udc.net$"
| regex fqdn!=".*?htc.com$"
| where match(fqdn,".")
```

I am trying them to combine with `|` separeted but not working though...

```
   | regex fqdn!="(.*?udc.net | ".*?htc.com)$"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `search` and `where` clause:

```
| inputlookup myfile.csv 
| search support_group="mygroup-Linux" u_sec_dom="Normal Secure"
| where !match(fqdn,"udc.net$") AND !match(fqdn,"htc.com$")
```

Or just a single `search` clause:

```
| inputlookup myfile.csv
| search support_group="mygroup-Linux" u_sec_dom="Normal Secure" NOT (fqdn IN("*udc.net","*htc.com")
```

You can also rewrite the `IN()` thusly:

```
(fqdn="*udc.net" OR fqdn="*htc.com")
```

Comment: do you have an idea in case i need to look for a string which has more than 5 digits in it like `inv010168062105.examle.com`  `"inv\d{10,}\.example\.com"`.

Comment: I can somewhat manage this like `| regex fqdn="(^inv\d{6})"` or `| regex fqdn="(\w{2}\d{6})"`

Comment: @KarnKumar - ask that in a separate question, instead of in the comments here :)

Answer (score 1):

The combined regex will work if you omit the spaces on either side of the `|`.  The extra spaces become part of the regex and prevent matches.

There's no need for the final `where` command.  Splunk by default will display all events that match `.`.

Comment: @ RichG, thanks for the answer ,  the first suggestion works however, `where` command is needed as to remove the `row` where feild `fqdn` is blank, if i remove `where` stateent then it also prints the all blank lines for the column `fqdn`.